# Cannot access <Button> with useRef()

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I'm trying to access my buttons element with useRef in react. But I don't know why when I click on one button it always returns me the last element.

Here is my code

```
const selectPage = (value) => {
      dispatch(Action.changePage(value));
      console.log(ref.current);
   };

   const returnButton = (value) => {
      return (
         <button
            onClick={() => {
               selectPage(value);
            }}
            ref={ref}
         >
            <GiBeerStein />
         </button>
      );
   };

return (
    {returnButton(1)}
    {returnButton(2)}
    {returnButton(3)}
)
```

Any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: The built in behavior for element refs only works for a single element. Anything else requires some custom code. What's your desired result? Do you want `ref.current` to be an array of elements?

Comment: @Nicholas Tower, I would like to set a specific classname on the clicking element by doing for exemple : ref.current.classname= active. I don't know if it answers a bit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't manually change the dom to add a classname. React will have no idea that you did so, and so it cannot take your change into account when it decides what future updates it needs to perform. In some cases, this may result in unexpected behavior, with react changing things you don't want to be changed, or vice versa.

Instead, you should use state. If you want exactly one button to be active at a time, then the state can be a number which is the index of the button that's active:

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

const selectPage = (value) => {
  dispatch(Action.changePage(value));
  setActiveIndex(value - 1);
};

const buttons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  buttons.push(
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        selectPage(i + 1);
      }}
      className={activeIndex === i ? "active" : undefined}
    >
      <GiBeerStein />
    </button>
  );
}

return <>{buttons}</>;
```

If instead you need to support multiple buttons being active, you can make the index an array of booleans:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState([false, false, false]);

const selectPage = (value) => {
  setActiveIndex(prev => {
    const next = [...prev];
    next[value - 1] = !next[value - 1];
    return next;
  });
};

// ...
className={active[i] ? "active" : undefined}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, learned some new things here.